# General CakePHP Model implementation

Tags: cakephp

its my first cake project and I wanna ask a basic question somewhing about implementations of models

I have to objects, users and vehicles.

Every user can have one vehicle, so the users table have a vehicle_id field.

What I want is a single page where i can add a user and, on the same page a car

```
//User model
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Vehicle' => array(
    'className' => 'Vehicle'
)
```

My question is, how does the add function has to look like /controller/view ?

Thank you very much!

Julius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your add function wouldn’t look too different to if it were just managing one model; you would just use `saveAll()` instead of `save()` and that will save related data too. In your case, `saveAll()` would save Vehicle data as well as the User data.

Your HTML form would have fields for both:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->begin('User');
    echo $this->Form->input('User.name');
    echo $this->Form->input('Vehicle.name');
    // and so on
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

And then you would process this in your controller on submission:

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('User and vehicle saved.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```